# BLToolKit save null instead of 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, bltoolkit

I have this weird problem where BLToolkit saves NULL instead of 0 in our database.

[Demo to reproduce the bug](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzznvANFApmVYU55UUxBS0FncTA/view?usp=sharing)

If you look the image, this is my values that will be saved. (gIdx stand for GroupIndex)
[image: Values when the Stored Procedure is being executed]

Here are the results in the database. If you look at the GroupIndex Column, i only have 1 and 2. (this thing happen also for the SortIndex column)
[image]

this is my stored proc. And the column is simply a NULL, INT

```
USE [ASTUSADMINISTRATION]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[stpr_GridColumnLayout_Update]    Script Date: 2015-06-22 08:08:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stpr_GridColumnLayout_Update]
    @ID AS [usrID],  
    @Width AS int,
    @Index AS int,
    @IsCellMerged AS [usrBoolean],
    @GroupIndex AS int,
    @SortIndex AS int,
    @SortDirectionType AS int,
    @SummaryItemType AS int,
    @UpdatedDate AS datetime OUTPUT,
    @UpdatedUser AS [usrUsername]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @UpdatedDate = GETDATE()

    -- Vérifier si c'est un groupe système
UPDATE [dbo].[GridColumnLayout] SET
    [Width] = @Width,
    [Index] = @Index,
    [IsCellMerged] = @IsCellMerged,
    [GroupIndex] = @GroupIndex, 
    [SortIndex] = @SortIndex,
    [SortDirectionType] = @SortDirectionType,
    [SummaryItemType] = @SummaryItemType,
    [UpdatedDate] = @UpdatedDate, 
    [UpdatedUser] = @UpdatedUser
  WHERE [GridColumnLayoutID] = @ID
END
```

Similar issue happens with a string. Only 1 character is saved. ( [more detail here](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/issues/369) )

Comment: Please, provide `UpdateValue` class definition

Comment: @ili `UpdateValue` is simply an `IList<TEntity>`. I updated to include the whole function. Sorry.

Comment: how `TEntity` is defined? this may occure if `[Nullable]` attribute is defined on property\field

Comment: @ili I have found the Issue the BLToolkit code you can check my Issue on Github https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/issues/369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The bug has been fix on July, 27th 2015

This is actually a bug of BLToolkit when using the `ExecuteForEach` method when inserting into a Database using a Stored Procedure.

[See the issue on the GitHub project](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/issues/369)